# Swift httppost data not inserting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift

I am trying to send data to php and insert it to mysql database but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried sending data to php just to encode it to json and echo it back to swift and it returns a result so it means that the php file received the data. However inserting the data is not working.

swift2 httppost

```
func post() {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/json/json.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    // Compose a query string
    let postString = "firstName=James&lastName=Bond";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Let’s convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

        do{

            let myJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = myJSON {
                // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                let firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String
                print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
            }


        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("JSON Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

    task.resume()

}
```

json.php

```
<?php
// Read request parameters
$firstName= $_REQUEST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_REQUEST["lastName"];// Store values in an array

$conn = mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "notify");

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user values('', '$firstName',   
'$lastName')");

 ?>
```

Comment: Where is your fields name ?You insert query i wrong check sql syntax first

Comment: @RahulSaxena It's not necessarily a SQL error (as the column names are optional if you are supplying all of the columns in the `INSERT` statement). But you're right insofar as it's best practice to include the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having the server just echo the request works, then the problem rests within the server, not the client code. I would suggest adding some error handling in the PHP code:

```
<?php

// specify that this will return JSON

header('Content-type: application/json');

// open database

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","notify");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => mysqli_connect_error(), "sqlerrno" => mysqli_connect_errno()));
    exit;
}

// get the parameters

$field1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["firstName"]);
$field2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["lastName"]);

// perform the insert

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('{$field1}', '{$field2}')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => mysqli_error($con), "sqlerrno" => mysqli_errno($con), "sqlstate" => mysqli_sqlstate($con));
} else {
    $response = array("success" => true);
}

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Notes:

1. I wouldn't recommend logging in as `root`.
2. Make sure you use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks (see point 1).
3. I don't know if your `user` table has other fields in it, but if so, you might want to specify the column names in the `insert` statement. Even if you only have those two columns, it's a good way to "future-proof" your code.
4. Note, I've changed this to generate JSON response. I do that because it makes it easier for the client code to parse and handle the response. I'll leave the `NSJSONSerialization` to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.

Comment: Needless to say, this won't fix the problem, but will let you diagnose it. I suspect authentication issue or problem with the table/column names or that there are other columns in that table which weren't specified in the SQL. But until we see the error message, we can't say.