# Post method nsdictionary to json object iOS objective c

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, post

I am trying to send an array of dictionaries to server and before that I am converting to json format

NOTE:- the server is working well my friend in android is getting the response and data for successful post method

below is my code of post method:-

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *tvarns = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
tvarns[@"order_cart"]=_order_cart;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tvarns
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
NSString* order_cart;

order_cart = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",order_cart);

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",order_cart];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//  Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
// Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/add_cartapi.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
//   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
    NSLog(@"Reply = %@", requestReply);
    //   NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);

}] resume];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The value which the server wants is

```
{"order_cart":[{"customer_id":"114","item_id":14,"_id":"591d3822f55e2270202d8ff1","item_name":"Bira White","item_quantity":"2","price":"180.0","qr_code":"table21","phone":"7008841769","customer_name":"Samanthaa"},{"customer_id":"114","item_id":15,"_id":"591d3822f55e2270202d8ff0","item_name":"Bira Blonde","item_quantity":"2","price":"200.0","qr_code":"table21","phone":"7008841769","customer_name":"Samanthaa"}]}
```

My nslog is

```
2017-06-28 16:16:41.334 Barebones[3139:211622] the data Details is {
"order_cart" : [
{
  "phone" : "9047038606",
  "item_quantity" : "7",
  "qr_code" : "table21",
  "item_name" : "Bottled Water",
  "price" : "175",
  "customer_id" : "116",
  "customer_name" : "Akshay"
},
{
  "phone" : "9047038606",
  "item_quantity" : "2",
  "qr_code" : "table21",
  "item_name" : "Fresh Lime Soda(Sweet, Salt, Plain)",
  "price" : "158",
  "customer_id" : "116",
  "customer_name" : "Akshay"
},
{
  "phone" : "9047038606",
  "item_quantity" : "2",
  "qr_code" : "table21",
  "item_name" : "Bottled Water",
  "price" : "50",
  "customer_id" : "116",
  "customer_name" : "Akshay"
},
{
  "phone" : "9047038606",
  "item_quantity" : "2",
  "_id" : "591d3822f55e2270202d8ff0",
  "item_name" : "Bira Blonde",
  "price" : "86",
  "qr_code" : "table21",
  "customer_id" : "116",
  "item_id" : "3971",
  "customer_name" : "Akshay"
},
{
  "phone" : "9047038606",
  "item_quantity" : "1",
  "qr_code" : "table21",
  "item_name" : "Bottled Water",
  "price" : "25",
  "customer_id" : "116",
  "customer_name" : "Akshay"
   }
 ]
}
 2017-06-28 16:16:41.485 Barebones[3139:211669] Reply =   {"order_id":3961,"success":1}
<script type='text/javascript'    src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'>.      </script>
<script>
var data_array='{"source":{"name":"Kre8Tives","id":"SJQ6kyA1","order_id":"3961"},"customer":{"firstname":"","mobile":""},"tabType":"table","tabId":"591d3790498782970be66302","tableNumber":"1","items":null}';
alert(data_array);
 var settings = {
'async': true,
'crossDomain': true,
'url': 'http://posistapi.com/api/v1/table_order/push?customer_key=8c982f5e9ef091e9d5c8fb142311b49a68049b102de5e0987ebce29755c454227fbc7573c7da4199f126524a3ac7a39a&tabtype=table',
'method': 'POST',
'headers': {
'postman-token': 'e200ae19-d083-a98a-6db3-53fc2f8bd73f',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'authorization': 'Basic [removed]',
'content-type': 'application/json'
},
'processData': false,
'data': data_array,
 'acceptUrl':'http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/order_confirm.php',
 'rejectUrl':'http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/order_confirm.php',
 'billPrintUrl':'http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/order_confirm.php'

}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
});
</script>
2017-06-28 16:16:41.486 Barebones[3139:211669] requestReply: (null)
```

I have converted to desired son format but still I am getting no reply from  server

Even if I send return the data what I send from server I get null!!why is that ???thanks in advance !!:)

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
include('order-function.php');
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{

  $order_cart=$_POST['order_cart'];

  $items=json_decode($order_cart,true);

include('dbconfig.php');
$response = array();
try
    {
        $total_item_price=0;

        foreach ($items['order_cart'] as $item) {   //['order_cart']

        $customer_id=$item['customer_id'];
        $customer_name=$item['customer_name'];
        $phone=$item['phone'];
    $_id=$item['_id'];
        $item_name=$item['item_name'];
        $item_quantity=$item['item_quantity'];
        $price=$item['price'];
        $qr_code=$item['qr_code'];

  $products[]=array(
      "_id"=>"$_id",
      "item_name"=> $item_name,
      "item_price"=> $price,
            "item_quantity"=> $item_quantity

    );          

    $price_new+=$price;


       $item_push[]=array(
      "id"=>"$_id",
      "rate"=> $price,
            "quantity"=> $item_quantity

    );
      }


      $product_details=json_encode($products);
    $add_to_cart = "INSERT INTO order_cart (customer_id,product_details,order_amount,qr_code) VALUES ('$customer_id','$product_details','$price_new','$qr_code')";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$add_to_cart);
      $order_id=mysqli_insert_id($conn);

        if ($result) {

    $data['source']=array("name"=>"Kre8Tives",
                            "id"=>"SJQ6kyA1",
                  "order_id"=>"$order_id"
                );
    $data['customer']=array(
                        "firstname"=>"$customer_name",
                   "mobile"=>"$phone"
                );
     $data['tabType']= "table";
       $data['tabId']= "591d3790498782970be66302";
       $data['tableNumber']= "1";

       //items
       $data_one=json_encode($item_push,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
       $data_new=json_decode($data_one);
       $data['items']=$data_new;

       $data_item=json_encode($data);


  $response["order_id"] = $order_id;
  $response["success"] = 1;

     // print_r(json_encode($data));die;


} else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
        }







 echo json_encode($response);
 push_order($data_item);

    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "error occured";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check your api in postman. Is it working or not?

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: is anything wrong in my conversion or so??@JitendraModi

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I am getting null I want the reply from server and there is no error in server side

Comment: Will you share demo ?

Comment: I am sending data converting to json is my conversion correct??

Comment: I dont have a demo only my current project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147810/discussion-between-jitendra-modi-and-akshay).

Comment: Have you check below posted answer ?

Comment: `jsonData` with `options:0` instead of `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`, and `[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];`. Get rid of `order_cart` and `post`.

Comment: @Larme still didn't wrk after ur changes:(

Comment: Add `[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];` too. `requestReply` show plenty of JavaScript.

Comment: Is the problm Solved??

Comment: nope @NileshJha

Comment: any ideas???@NileshJha

Comment: I do not think it's correct to say that there is "no server side issue". I think the android code is ignoring mistakes in the web service response. On top of extraneous stuff being included after the JSON response in the body, this web service code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks because it's neither escaping nor parameterizing the input values. Very dangerous.

Comment: On the SQL injection attack issue (which is unrelated to your problems here), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34103945/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196541/1271826 for examples on how to use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, looking at your `NSLog` results, it looks like the server code is erroneously returning some extra HTML (starting at the `<script>` line) after the JSON result. Looking at the body of the `$response`, it's reporting success, but it looks like some extra text is included in the response, either as a result of `push_order`, or some HTML after after the `%>`, or some web service error that is inserting some extra HTML.

Focusing on your client request code, it should set the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers, though that’s not critical. But well designed requests should do that. The key issue is that the PHP should be outputting nothing else before or after the outputting of the JSON.

For what it's worth, if your web service was expecting a true JSON request, I would suggest a series of simplifications to your client code (in addition to setting those two additional headers). For example, just send the output of `NSJSONSerialization` as the `httpBody`; don't take that `NSData`, convert it to a `NSString` and then convert it back to a `NSData`. Just send `jsonData` as `httpBody`:

```
NSDictionary *tvarns = @{@"order_cart": _order_cart};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tvarns
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];

// if you want to see the JSON, you can do this, but this is not needed
//
// NSString *order_cart = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// NSLog(@"%@",order_cart);

// none of this stuff is needed; at worst, it can introduce encoding problems; at best, it's inefficient to do all that stuff
//
// NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",order_cart];
// NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
// NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
// //  Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
// NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

// Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our jsonData

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/add_cartapi.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// you don't need this, because NSURLSession sets the length for you
//
// [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// use the original jsonData here

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

// you should, if you're a good web-service citizen, set the header; it's not always needed, but it's advisable

// tell the server that you're sending JSON request

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// tell the server that you're expecting JSON response

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

// Unless you need a new session for some reason, it's better to use the shared session

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }

    if (!data) {
        return;
    }

    NSError *parseError;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
    if (jsonDict) {
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"parseError: %@", parseError);
        NSLog(@"response: %@", response); // when you have failure, it's sometimes useful to see what this says
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // this is json string
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    }
}] resume];
```

Again, having suggested these simplifications, I really suspect that there's a bug in the server code, including all that junk after the `<script>...`. I bet your Android code is ignoring all of this erroneous data at the end of the response, whereas `NSJSONSerialization` is correctly pointing out that the response is not, technically, well-formed JSON. (By the way, my code above will correctly log the JSON error.)

---

Looking at your PHP code that you've added to your revised question, it's grabbing `$order_cart=$_POST['order_cart'];`, which means that your web service is expecting a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. The PHP code then proceeds to define `$items` as `json_decode($order_cart,true)` and then iterate with `foreach` through `$items['order_cart']`. That means that the web service is expecting `x-www-form-urlencoded` request whose value associated with `order_cart` key is, itself, a JSON dictionary keyed by `order_cart` (again), i.e., the request body will look like `order_cart={"order_cart":[...]}`.

That's not a very elegant design, but if you're stuck with that, you're going to have to create `x-www-form-urlencoded` request whose key is `order_cart` and whose value is a percent-encoded representation of a JSON dictionary of the form `{"content-type":[...]}`.

```
NSDictionary *tvarns = @{@"order_cart": _order_cart};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tvarns
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"order_cart=%@", [jsonString stringByAddingPercentEncodingQueryValue]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/add_cartapi.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

// Unless you need a new session for some reason, it's better to use the shared session

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }

    if (!data) {
        return;
    }

    NSError *parseError;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
    if (jsonDict) {
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"parseError: %@", parseError);
        NSLog(@"response: %@", response); // when you have failure, it's sometimes useful to see what this says
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // this is json string
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    }
}] resume];
```

Where:

```
@interface NSCharacterSet (URLQueryValue)

/**
 Character set of characters allowed within value (or a key) in a application/x-www-form-urlencode key/value pair.

 @return NSCharacterSet of allowed characters.
 */
+ (NSCharacterSet *) URLQueryValueAllowedCharacterSet;

@end

@implementation NSCharacterSet (URLQueryValue)

+ (NSCharacterSet *) URLQueryValueAllowedCharacterSet {
    static NSString * const generalDelimitersToEncode = @":#[]@"; // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
    static NSString * const subDelimitersToEncode = @"!$&'()*+,;=";

    NSString * const characterToEncode = [generalDelimitersToEncode stringByAppendingString:subDelimitersToEncode];

    NSMutableCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
    [cs removeCharactersInString:characterToEncode];
    return cs;
}

@end
```

And

```
@interface NSString (URLQueryValue)
/**
 String percent encoding for key or value in key/value pair within an application/x-www-form-urlencoded request.

 @return Percent encoded string.
 */
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEncodingQueryValue;
@end

@implementation NSString (URLQueryValue)
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEncodingQueryValue {
    return [self stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
}
@end
```

Frankly, I'd suggest changing the web service to process a true JSON request, not JSON within a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. If you did that, the client code would look more like my original answer above. But for your existing web service code, you'd create something like my second code sample.

Comment: okay thank you for your help I ll let you know the updates!!:)

Comment: parseError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: I am getting this error@Rob is this error in server code?

Comment: Yep, the body of the response should just be `{"order_id":3961,"success":1}`, with nothing before it and nothing after it. But you appear to have a bunch of junk (possibly output by `push_order`). By the way, someone is likely to chime in and point out that you can use `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` when converting the response to JSON, but I think that's a bad idea, merely camouflaging web service bugs. You really should fix the server code to not include this extra junk.

Comment: Barebones[1202:198523] requestReply: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/kre8tume/public_html/www.godzgeek.com/barebon/add_cartapi.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
{"order_id":4211,"success":1}  and now am getting this I have told server side to remove the push_order  and still data is not received it is 0 and null @Rob

Comment: I don’t know if you want to remove `push_order` or not. It depends what that does. The original error suggested that is there some more stuff after the `%>`. But this new error is different, pointing out that it’s grabbing `order_cart` from `$_POST`. And then `for_each` is looking for _another_ `order_cart` within that. That seems weird. The error makes sense.

Comment: but this is the whole php code:( the error line is foreach ($items['order_cart'] as $item)  and I am nt a  backend dev so I dont know php !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148106/discussion-between-rob-and-akshay).

Comment: @Akshay - I've added code snippet that should create request that can be consumed that that curious PHP code.

Comment: Now the code is not executed when the action is done!!!it doesn't go inside session it skips it @Rob

Comment: You should post a new question outlining the problem, showing a [simplified, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried, describe what happened, and then show us what really happened, including any debugging you did. But, yes, it definitely will reach the code after the asynchronously executed `dataTaskWithRequest` block, itself, runs, but the block should eventually run when the request is done. But we can't diagnose that on the basis of your description in your comment, and this particular question has already dragged on too long.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"order_cart": _order_cart};
NSLog(@"dict = %@", dict);

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];

// For debug
NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"postString = %@", postString);
//

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/add_cartapi.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        id jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        NSLog(@"jsonDict = %@", jsonDict);
        if (!error) {

        }
        else {

        }
    }
    else {

    }
}];

[task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass directly NSData to HttpBody like below :

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"application/json",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache"
                         };

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tvarns
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/add_cartapi.php"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Hope this will helps to get your data request success!

Comment: are you passing proper data in JSON data dictionary right ?

Comment: yea the data is proper and I have posted a sample of working data too(i.e. from android team) :( have above "the data which serve wants" is an example of working android teams post data

Comment: I dont understand whats the issue here:(

Comment: Sorry But I forget to add header of content-type please try with my updated answer.

Comment: the line "data using encoding" gives me error no interface found

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: I did changes to make code work and I got 2017-06-28 17:43:31.593 Barebones[3334:262015] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108642b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171

Comment: this is the error the above code gave me.  Barebones[3354:263902] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102be4b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147820/discussion-between-codechanger-and-akshay).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
NSMutableDictionary *parametersDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"114" forKey:@"customer_id"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"14" forKey:@"item_id"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"591d3822f55e2270202d8ff1" forKey:@"_id"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"Bira White" forKey:@"item_name"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"2" forKey:@"item_quantity"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"180.0" forKey:@"price"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"table21" forKey:@"qr_code"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"7008841769" forKey:@"phone"];
[parametersDictionary setValue:@"Samanthaa" forKey:@"customer_name"];

NSMutableDictionary *requestParametersDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:parametersDictionary,@"order_cart", nil];

NSData * postData=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestParametersDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];


NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",KWebservicesBaseURL,kiPestConfirmOrder]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc]init];

    if(data!=nil && httpResponse.statusCode==200)
    {
        responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // NSLog(@"i deliver add order reponse str %@",responseString);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: 2017-06-28 16:57:09.325 Barebones[3251:237750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001073f7b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106e63141 objc_exception_throw + 48

Comment: I think because I have already done ":NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted" above recheck the question doing writing pretty leads to error I guess

Comment: Yes, could you please send me your NSMutableDictionary, so i can test and confirm you

Comment: are you asking for the datas of my dictionary which I am sending to server??

Comment: Yes, send me all Key-Value pairs

Comment: it is above in my log

Comment: I.e. the data details is " ########" what ever is in quotes is my data which I am sending

Comment: yea but those data are dynamically chosen by user!!

Comment: I dont think there is a method Called convertjsontodictionary and it gives me error no visible interface

Comment: Please see my edit response as I am getting {"order_id":3968,"success":1} from server. If it not works on your side then problem is must with your dictionary.

Comment: Please ignore that NSLog line, this is on from my side

Comment: did u get reply??response gives everyone the next order id and success :1

Comment: actually the server replies with the order id and success1; response gives us that

Comment: Yes I got that. Have you?

Comment: in server I am not getting anything

Comment: Then this issue must be from server side not app side. If this answer helps you in any manner. Please accept :)

Comment: ha ha :)....I am trying from morn !!there is no server side issue as the android team uses the same api and it works fine for them!!:(

Answer (score 0):

Your array is correct just convert to json string

Here is func for that

```
public func jsonString(prettify: Bool = false) -> String? {
        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(self) else {
            return nil
        }
```

Use it this way

```
 self.arrOrderCart.jsonString()
```

Comment: I think this line.  order_cart = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; does the conversion